# What is the difference in between adding "read" or "read -rn1" to the end of a bash script?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I've written a simple bash script for running rsync in between two directories, and I wanted it to keep the terminal window open after it runs, so I can check if everything went fine.

So, I found two different solutions in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446391/how-to-prevent-terminal-window-from-closing-when-linux-bash-script-terminates), that is adding either the command `read` or `read -rn1` to the end of the script, and I'm wondering what would be the difference in between them, and if I should prefer using one over the other, since both seems to do the same.

Answer (score 2):

`read` waits for a line ending with a newline, then ends. So only the enter key allows you to complete the command and, therefore in your case, to close the terminal window.

`read -n1` waits for a single character, then ends. So a single press on any key terminates the command and, therefore in your case, closes the terminal window.

However, I don't see the usefulness of the -r option in your case

For more info on the bash builtin command `read`:

- `man bash` (see `read` in the `SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS` section)
- `help -m read`

Comment: I guess the distinction is that without the `-r`, it will actually need 2 keystrokes to terminate in the case that the user hits `\ `. With `-r`, even  `\ ` will count as one character.

Answer (score 0):

You can run `read --help` to see what `-rn1` does.

Running `read -rn1` is the same as `read -r -n1`

> -r            do not allow backslashes to escape any characters
>
> -n nchars return after reading NCHARS characters rather than waiting
>             for a newline, but honor a delimiter if fewer than
>             NCHARS characters are read before the delimiter